# Connect Mongodb Atlas to GKE via VPC Network Peering

Tags: google-kubernetes-engine, mongodb-atlas, cidr, google-vpc, gke-networking

I'm looking for a general set of steps to connect a GKE pod to Mongodb Atlas.

I have a GKE cluster with two pods, a client pod and a server pod. I have an ingress, which I use to access the client pod, and which I use to access the server pod from the client.

I want to get data from my Atlas db with my server pod. I'm reading questions like this: [GKE not able to reach MongoDB Atlas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62104559/gke-not-able-to-reach-mongodb-atlas) and articles like this: [How to Securely Connect MongoDB Atlas Projects to Cloud-Offered Kubernetes Clusters](https://www.mongodb.com/developer/how-to/connect-atlas-cloud-kubernetes-peering/) but I need a basic explanation of what is happening.

- Do I need Cloud NAT on GKE if I'm using VPC Network Peering?
- Why is    it not enough to just whitelist my static Ingress IP in
  Atlas?
- Can I create my VPC network declaratively with a yaml instead of
  imperatively as shown in this doc [enter link description here](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/using-vpc) or
  do I absolutely have to use Terraform to do that? (too complicated at this
  stage)
- How do I assign subnets in GKE and Atlas? There doesn't seem to be much control on CIDR ranges? I am very new to this but quite confused about how to set it all up?

Here is a diagram of how I envisage things working:

[image: Basic pod routing]

[image: Peering]

What are the steps to set this up?

Comment: Have you tried anything already ? Encountered any issues etc or you're just asking theoretically ? Cloud NAT would be useful if you need to use public IP's - otherwise it's not necessary. You can deploy your resources (networking included) with [Deployment manager](https://cloud.google.com/deployment-manager/docs/quickstart#deploy_the_resources).

Comment: I've set up VPC Network Peering between mongodb Atlas and GCP. I'm really stuck how to connect my server pod in GKE to Atlas using the connection?

Comment: Are the hosts from Atlas VPC able to ping the ones in GKE VPC and the opposite ?

Comment: I can't ping either way. I have auto-generated peering routes, but I can't ping the Atlas CIDR from the gcloud terminal or from one of my pods.

Comment: Just for testing - create one VM in each VPC an test if they can ping each other.

Comment: Ok I have VMs in GKE which correspond to my pods - I SSH into them and can't ping from those either - I do docker run --rm busybox ping 192.168.0.0 -c 2

Comment: I don't understand how to create an Atlas VM in my VPC and ping from the other direction

Comment: If you already have a VPC created for your AtlasDB then create a regular Debian VM in it and try again.

Comment: I can only connect to the db from mongosh via my client terminal. To connect to the VPC I would need to connect to the network - I only created the VPC by the Atlas console, I don't have access to a mongosh terminal from there?

Comment: I'm not familiari with AtlasDB so that's why I asked to create simple VM's in each VPC network so we can try if the peering works.